# Extending Linux Partition

Tags: partition, gparted

I have two hard discs. On the second one, I have the Linux Partition. I want to extend it, but I don't know how. I'm quite the beginner, so and extended guide or a link to one would be usefull.

Linux is on sdb5. It's not possible to increase the size by clicking the 'Resize' option. Also, please tell me which mistakes I definitely should avoid.

[image]

Comment: Your drive is effectively full. Time for new larger drive or major housecleaning of old data. Windows NTFS really wants 30% free to work well. At 10% free you just about cannot do a defrag as no working room. And Windows gets slow if you do not have lots of space. Linux formatted partitions also need some space, but not as much as NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

A partition can be extended if there is free space after it. Which is not the case here.

The disk has a little bit of unallocated space, but it is not much to begin with, and it is located *before* the Linux partition and broken into three different sections. I am not aware of a tool that can "compress" the free storage; perhaps there is one in the Windows world?

One thing you should avoid is moving partitions around without a backup of your data.